# Convergence and absolute convergence of series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Prove that if $\sum{{a_n}^2} $ and $\sum{{b_n}^2} $ both converge then $\sum{a_nb_n} $converges absolutely.

We know that $\sum{(a_n + b_n)^2} $ = $\sum{{a_n}^2} $ + $2\sum{{a_n b_n}} $ +$\sum{{b_n}^2}$

Should we use this ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the fact that $|a_nb_n| \leq \frac{1}{2}(a_n^2+b_n^2)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then apply the hypthothesis to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $\sum_{k=1}^N |a_kb_k|\leq \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^N a_k^2\sum_{k=1}^N b_k^2}\leq \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^2\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k^2} $.

The partial sums of $\sum_{k} |a_kb_k|$ are bounded, so the series converges, hence $\sum_{k} a_kb_k$ converges absolutely.